# How to use Google Calendar API for the first time on Linux?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

You can use google-calerdar-api from this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python).

I use this code(python3.X) to get data of calendar on windows 10.

Python Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'

def main():
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('./credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', alwaysIncludeEmail=True,
                                          timeMin='2017-01-01T00:00:00+09:00',timeMax='2019-01-05T23:59:59+09:00',
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])
    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I first used the example code of this api,this information appears in the pycharm console.

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1132573726-nu1pktj3jt03qjigful1cq32p97eu.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&access_type=offline&response_type=code

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

Then my browser pops up a page like this.
[image]

Then I clicked my account.

On this page I clicked `Allow`.

[image]

Then the browser displays the message.

[image]

Then the console of pycharm appears this:

```
Authentication successful.
Getting the upcoming 10 events
2018-01-15T08:30:00+09:00 20180115
2019-01-01T10:00:00+09:00 hello
2019-01-02T11:00:00+09:00 20190102_test1
2019-01-03T11:30:00+09:00 20190103_test1
2019-01-04T11:00:00+09:00 20190104_test1
```

So the code runs successfully.I see file `token.json` in the folder of code.

**But my question is, I can't use browser on Linux(centos), so how can I allow my account to operate like Windows the first time?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ouaht2 and user consent**

If you want to access a users private data then you will always have to have them authenticate your application at least once.   The only way to do that is with a web browser window.

The first thing that happens is that a user must login to their google account via a browser, once they have logged in they will be presented with the consent screen asking them to give your application access to their data.

In this manner a user consents to your application accessing their data.

**Development for Linux users.**

I am curious as to why you think that Linux users will be running your application.  I have not seen many people designing natively applications to run on linux.  WTG you.

Users running Linux will have to open the to open a web browser, this can be done though the windows desktop.  If they are running command line then they will have to copy the link and open it on a browser.  I dont think the command line web browser will work here its going to have to be done though the linux desktop.

**Service account**

Now as you seam to be worried about Linux users I am wondering if you are not really worried about users of your application actually.

Are you are attempting to run this application in say a cron job on a linux server?  Assuming as well that you are only trying to access a single account one that you personally control.   Then you could use what is called a service account.  Service accounts are intended for server to server communication where there is really no user present at login time to approve the consent.    For a service account to work they must be pre-approved.   Once you have created the service account in Google developer console you simply take the service account email address and share the calendar you wish it to have access to via the google calendar website.  Once the calendar has been shared with the service account it will have access to that calendar and you will not have to worry about the web browser authentication.

Comment: Do you mean a Linux desktop likes ubuntu?Except ubuntu, it seems that only this command `Yum group install "X Window System"` can installed Linux desktop on centos.

Comment: I am a little confused why you are trying to run this in linux.   Do you have personal control of the account you are trying to access?   are you trying to run this as a cron job?

Comment: Hi,I have admin account of my company when I use the google-calendar-api.I can get gmail account of staff.And the server is linux,so I must run it on linux as cron job. As you said,I think I need install linux desktop.

Comment: I just get the calendar data of the whole staff as an administrator, and then put these data into the database, just to process the data into the database, no user will access the application, because no application for staff.

Comment: Are these gsuite accounts by any change?  If it is then the gsuite admin can give the service account access to the whole domain.

Comment: Hi,In fact, as an administrator, I get everybody's gmail account of my company, use everybody's gmail account as `calendarId` to loop everybody's data, and after getting these data, I do some processing and put the processed data into the database. But we have not developed an application to allow employee to access each other's calendars, just the DBA needs the data.

Comment: If you have access to their accounts.  Then you could give the service account access to each of their calendars.   Then the service account will have access to them all.   The only other way to do this would be to have each user authenticate an application using the code you have now save the refresh token store the refresh token on the server for each of the users and use that to get a new access token when ever you need access.  This solution would be very messy and prone to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the authentication part in a web browser. To complete the authentication from a different machine/browser, you can complete the rest of the authentication using the OOB (out of band) flow. The oauth library you're using hinted that you can use this OOB flow by passing the --noauth_local_webserver to the program you're running on (alternatively, you can add the flag to sys.argv somehow), open the provided URL on a browser, and then you will have to copy back the verification code manually.

Note that oauth2client.tools isn't intended to be programmatic interface. Its intended use is for interactive CLI application and as an example of how to integrate the library with your own app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows and don't have any grahical browser on Linux, an easy solution is to run the application with `--noauth_local_webserver` on Linux and then on Windows connect to the Linux server with PuTTY and bring the server's TCP port 8888 to your local system.

- First make sure you don't have anything on Windows already listening on that port (e.g. by running: `netstat -na|findstr ":8888 "|findstr /C:LISTENING`).
- Then you need to open the SSH connection with PuTTY.
- Once connected click the icon in the top left of the PuTTY window and go to Change Settings / Connection / SSH / Tunnels, set Source port to 8888, destination to 127.0.0.1:8888 and select Local and Auto.
- You can now check by browsing to http://127.0.0.1:8888/, which should show an error message other than not being able to connect.
- Then open the browser on Windows and start the activation. When the browser gets redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8888 it will go straight to the application on the Linux server and activate it.

Note that you can do similar thing from macOS. But instead of PuTTY you need to open a Terminal and run `ssh -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888 <user>@<linuxserver>`

[image: PuTTY screenshot]